# how to implement lazyloading in the adapter

Tags: android, lazy-loading

Hi, I am trying to learn the concept of lazyloading.Every where I see the title outline ,but how exactly it is implemented , couldn't find pattern it follow.I found the following code from lazylist project in github.

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private String[] data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, String[] d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

        TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);;
        ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
        text.setText("item "+position);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], image);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

can someone explain how the images are lazy loaded..I am trying to implement a adapter where the list need to use lazyloading..not sure how to implement.
http://pastebin.com/EPfMBRA1  here I am trying to load my contacts with images in the device
Any help/suggestions are appreciated.